# Store hashMap in array

Tags: java, hashmap

I would like to store HashMaps in an array. I'm trying to make just one HashMap, fill it with specific information and store it into one element of an array. Then I would like to overwrite the information in that Hashmap with different information and then store that into a different element of that array. I would like to do this multiple times. What's the best way to go about doing this?

Right now I have:

```
HashMap[][] location = new HashMap[columns][rows];
HashMap <String, String> area = new HashMap <String, String> ();

public Map() {

    area.put("description", "You are in the upper left\n");
    location[0][0] = area;

    area.put("description", "You are in the upper middle\n");
    location[1][0] = area;
}
```

The problem with this is that now both location[0][0] and location[1][0] have the same description.

Comment: You should use Map for area instead of HashMap. It's a good practice in the sense that it'll be easier to change implementation in future.

Comment: I'm not sure if my area and your area are the same. I'm using area in terms of a location on a map, not mathematically. Is using a HashMap better in my case?

Comment: You are confusing the literal meaning of Map with the Map interface of Java. I meant you should initialize your area variable as, Map<String, String> area = new HashMap <String, String>(); This would help you in future when you want to shift to let say LinkedHashMap, Treemap or any other flavor of Map.

Comment: I didn't think of that. In fact, I didn't know those other ones even existed. Thanks.

Comment: Then I suggest you take a look at them and figure out the benefactions over one another. It's always good to have a reason before choosing a data structure. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

location[0][0] and location[1][0] hold the same pointer to area

you should do like this

```
location[0][0] = createArea("You are in the upper left\n");
location[1][0] = createArea("You are in the upper middle\n");



HashMap <String, String> createArea(String desc){
    HashMap <String, String> area = new HashMap <String, String> ();
    area.put("description", desc);
    return area;
}
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks. I like how simple it is. I knew I needed to make a new HashMap but I couldn't picture what the code would look like. Methods are key.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a different instance of the `Map` to be stored in each location.

```
 public Map() {      

   Map<String, String> area = new HashMap<String, String>();
   area.put("description", "You are in the upper left\n");     
   location[0][0] = area;      

   area = new HashMap<String, String>();
   area.put("description", "You are in the upper middle\n");    
   location[1][0] = area; }
```